# Installing armhf libboost-python-dev in amd64 cross environ

Tags: debian, python, cross-compilation

I'm trying to install `libboost-python-dev` for `armhf` in `amd64` cross compilation build environment.

```
apt install libboost-python-dev:armhf
```

`libboost-python-dev` depends on `python2.7-minimal`, which depends on `python`. Since the architecture of `libboost-python-dev` should be `armhf`, the hole chain of dependencies should be `armhf` in order for things to work. Problem is, `python2.7-minimal` runs python scripts at the postinstallation stage, so it tries to use python interpreter `/usr/bin/python`. Alas, the interpreter cannot run, since it is ARM binary, and the host machine is AMD64.

How do I solve this?